# Android lifecycle library: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an app I'm working on that's using the lifecycle library but I'm getting an IllegalArgumentException that says "Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles" I only add observers in onCreate which I thought would be safe. Most of my observers are added via anonymous classes which I assume can't be the issue here since the observer is never recycled. One is using `this`:

```
private GpsState gpsState;

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLifecycle().addObserver(gpsState);
    gpsState.observe(this, (state) -> {
        // ...
    });
}
```

In this example `GpsState` extends `LiveData` to provide the current state of the GPS and implements `LifecycleObserver` to be able to refresh certain values when reaching an ON_RESUME state.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In my case the problem was at lambda method of observer is empty. I just tried to add something to it and problem was solved. For example:

```
gpsState.observe(this, (state) -> {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), BaseNavigationActivity.this.toString());

});
```

Most likely that JVM define anonymous classes that use only static references and for such cases it become kinda singleton, so you will have same instance all the time you reference such class.

Comment: Very close, it wasn't empty but it was only accessing static objects which I guess made the compiler reuse the same instance.

Comment: If you use Timber: `Timber.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName());` I was just using `Timber.i("...");` and it wasn't enough.

Comment: Yeah, seems you have to add some dynamic thing to it

Comment: It worked for me too. But can you explain why this works?

Comment: No. It's not working in fragment

Answer (score 40):

As [thehebrewhammer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025233/android-lifecycle-library-cannot-add-the-same-observer-with-different-lifecycle#comment82402943_47264913) said in a comment, I had the same issue because of Kotlin SAM-Lambda optimization.

```
viewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
    NavigationBackEvent().post()
})
```

This SAM-Lambda doesn't access anything of the class and will be compiled to a singleton for optimization.
I changed it to a class initialization for forcing new instance at each run:

```
viewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, MyObserver())
```

and

```
class MyObserver : Observer<MyType?> {
    override fun onChanged(it: MyType?) {
        NavigationBackEvent().post()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why lots of examples which uses `this, Observer {...}` works? For example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/GardenFragment.kt

Comment: @VasilyKabunov It's all related to the fact that if you don't access field of the "parent class". If you access one, the compiler make a `inner class`. If you don't access, no need to instance multiple time, it's always the same. The compiler will optimize it and make a singleton.

Comment: your a life saver ..saved me countless hours.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, these lines of code solved it:

```
sharedViewModel.getFriendsList().observe(this, object: Observer<ArrayList<User>> {
    override fun onChanged(t: ArrayList<User>?) {
        CurrentUser.friendsList = t
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on previous responses all you need to do is create a new `Object` every time you subscribe your observer.

```
gpsState.observe(this, object: Observer<GpsState> {
    // ...
});
```

PD: I assumed that `GpsState` is the data type you want observe. In my case was `Long`