# How to fix Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles Error

Tags: android, android-room, android-lifecycle

I have read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025233/android-lifecycle-library-cannot-add-the-same-observer-with-different-lifecycle) but I didn't understand anything. So please don't remove this question and answer me.
I have a Fragment that it intents to another Activity. In the Fragment I use getLifecycleOwner as lifecycle owner of rooms observer.
When I go to the Activity, I use this as Lifecycle owner but the Application crashes and shows me this error:  Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles Error.

This is observer's lifecycle owner of the fragment: `productViewModel.getLiveEditedValue().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), s -> productRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged());`

And this is the observer in the Activity:

```
dbViewModel.getAllNews().observe(this, new Observer<List<NewsLetter>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<NewsLetter> newsLetters) {
                if(newsLetters == null || newsLetters.isEmpty()){
                    getAllNews(BaseCodeClass.CompanyID,1577865695);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Has data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

So what should I do?

I know this question has been answered before but first, I didn't understand and second I believe that was not my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the Fragment, use:

[**Kotlin**]

```
val owner = activity as LifeCycleOwner
productViewModel.getLiveEditedValue().observe(owner, Observer { s ->
    // UI update here
})
```

[**Java**]

```
LifecycleOwner owner = (LifecycleOwner) getActivity();
productViewModel.getLiveEditedValue().observe(owner, s -> productRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged());
```